# Changing the default ValueError of file.index

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

I was using `file.index` to search for a string in a file.

```
def IfStringExistsInFile(self,path,lineTextCheck):
    file = open(path).read()
    if file.index(lineTextCheck):
        print (lineTextCheck + " was found in: " + path)
    else:
        raise ValueError (lineTextCheck + " was NOT found in: " + path)
```

My issue is that if it does not find the string, it automatically raises a default ValueError and does not go into the "else" code which contains my custom ValueError:

```
ValueError: substring not found
```

Is there a way I could change that default ValueError?

Currently, the only way I came up with was to wrap the sentence with "try except", like so:

```
def IfStringExistsInFile(self,path,lineTextCheck):
    file = open(path).read()
    try:
        if file.index(lineTextCheck):
            print (lineTextCheck + " was found in: " + path)
    except:
            raise ValueError(lineTextCheck + " was NOT found in: " + path)
```

Any better way would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> Any better way would be greatly appreciated

You solved it exactly how this should be solved.

Note that you can create your own `Exception` by creating a class that inherits from `BaseException`, but this is rarely needed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you cant change the built in errors. When you `raise` an error you raise it wherever you want, but in cause you done `except` the built-in error you will still get that.

So your second solution is the best i think, to `except` the built-in error, and treat it with a `raise`

Answer (score 1):

[*Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Using a `try/except` for this is standard practice. You can also drop that `if` so the line gets printed if the index is found without raising errors:

```
try:
    file.index(lineTextCheck)
    print (lineTextCheck + " was found in: " + path)
except ValueError: # explicitly specify the error
    raise ValueError(lineTextCheck + " was NOT found in: " + path)
```